# Can we use article the with water

Tags: articles

Can I use article " the"  in this blank.

> Fill the tumbler with  ___ water.

I have researched a lot and I found that "the"  can be used with some uncountable nouns but I am still confused with this blank given above.
Everybody is telling me that in this blank we have to use "the" before water.
Please help me with this

Answer (score 3):

The use of an article would only be appropriate if a particular sample of water was being referred to.

*On the table is a jug of water which contains a few drops of food colouring. Fill the tumbler with the water.*